# Solution needed for a usb 3 hub plus ssd to thunderbolt 1

Tags: connection

I've looked occasionally to no avail over the last 18 months and also find it soooo confusing because of the multitude of Port types invented and limitations of my mac to come up with a solution. Please advise if this is at all possible or not.

I own an imac 27" late 2013 edition with only 2x thunderbolt 1 ports (i know it sucks bad right!?)
I have an ssd connected up via one of the 4x usb 3 ports to use as a system drive in an tdsp enclosure.

Because it's connected through usb i can't utilise any trim software so I'd like to connect it through the thunderbolt port which apparently allows the use of trim(?).

Id also like to expand the amount of usb 3 ports i have available so i can connect more devices up. Instead of using a usb hub that connected to an existing usb port (which would hinder data throughput rate) i wanted to take advantage of cheap usb-c hubs as they are compatible with thunderbolt 3 (which in turn is compatible with thunderbolt 1 albeit with an adaptor).

How can i achieve this?, as cheaply as possible as some of the thunderbolt stuff out there is extortionately priced!?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this functionality, you probably need to look at purchasing a Thunderbolt to eSATA adaptor - e.g. Kanex, Startech. These are not cheap (between US$ 70 - 100) but eSATA is the native interface for your storage device and therefore all commands should be available through this. Some of these adapters will also give you an additional USB port which you may find useful.

Thunderbolt 3 uses the USB-C connector but don't rely on USB-C hubs being completely Thunderbolt 3 compatible (unless you can find something on the net that says someone has managed to get it to work).

Comment: thanks for the advice. why someone would vote down this question I don't know. it's a valid question.